# Twitter callback Web Intents Javascript Events

Tags: twitter, tracking

Is it possible to pass some variables to the called function,

it tried it like this but failed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('tweet', twitnshare('tws_likings', '<?php echo $sess_uid;?>', href));
});</script>
```

If its not possible, whats the way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered in place on our dev forums:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/671

Comment: Thanks for the great help.. but still am stuck somewhere..

The tweet button is in a while loop as the posts has to loaded with a while loop, so tweet button is then attached to every post accordingly..

Surely it fires the event but don't know why it fires 10 times..
Element id has to be same every time because it has been defined only once..

Getting 10 similar entries in the dayabase with every new tweet..

Answer (score 2):

Usually if the events binding is not working i have found ppl missing the assign to windows.twttr before binding an event to it. First do this :

```
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
  js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

Than do the bindings:

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) { //add ur post tweet stuff here } );
});
```

Following links might help :
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events#events

> https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/671

Comment: This solved it. Only other thing--make sure the platform.twitter.com script is http rather than https if you're not secure.