# Twitter ready does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, callback

I got some of this code from another stack overflow question and another part from a tutorial

Why does ready not fire?

```
window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        $('.twitter-timeline').show();
    }
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    alert('ready');
});
```

Is there something wrong with this part?

```
twttr.ready(function(twttr){
```

Comment: Where exactly did you get this? The `window.twttr` function doesn't return anything so it doesn't have a `.ready()` method.

Comment: someone +1 it on another question

Comment: on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846651/twitter-callback-web-intents-javascript-events

Comment: That's not the same what you have. They have a line at the end that returns the `twttr` object.

Comment: Thank you [juhana](http://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana)!